# mcopy alternatives for windows users

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, operating-system, osdev

I am trying to compile a custom operating system by following a youtube tutorial. However the video instructs using mcopy, from gnu mtools, of which I cannot seem to install using the package managers I currently use.

I use primarily chocolaty and mingw32 to install the packages that I need, but these have not worked in order.

For reference, the command I am trying to run is the following, which attempts to copy the kernel onto a FAT12 unmounted filesystem.

`mcopy -i $(BLD)/main_floppy.iso $(BLD)/kernel.bin "::kernel.bin"`

I'd also rather not run the command with elevated privileges.

Please note that I am a complete noob to this kind of work (thus why I am using a tutorial) so if the question is a bit silly, please understand

If there are any alternatives I can use or ways to install/run the command on windows (maybe installing it manually or using WSL) the help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It appears someone has an older version for Windows available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RPvFdft4pUOXZxvl1SjecKs2mG33f6F0/view?usp=drive_web) that may work.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up giving in and learning docker and I'm quite happy with the result. Using a shared volume I could use my source files from my desktop and output all the needed files.